# CoreData predicate @"nameOfEntity ==[c] %@"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I got this old project which uses coredata as a persistent store. Problem is it has this kind of  predicate for fetching entity:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameOfEntity ==[c] %@", entityName];
```

I couldn't find what this [c] refers inside this predicate.

Could anyone enlight me into this. I searched everywhere I could.

Comment: [vikingosegundo answer's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25302386/468724) is straight forward but the problem here is the usage of less commenting.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, "usage of less commenting" can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: it means the code should have lot's of comments.

Comment: This code speaks for itself. you just must be able to read it. I usually do not comment single lines, just methods. Or one day I would up writing this : `i++; // increments i by one`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it means case insensitive. `Name`, `name`, `NAME` will all detected as the same.

> String comparisons are by default case and diacritic sensitive. You can modify an operator using the key characters c and d within square braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively, for example `firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] $FIRST_NAME.`

[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868)